# neovim spits out weird character on terminal upon closing

Tags: neovim

I have install neovim and linked the .vimrc to the .config/nvim/init file. neovim splits out the following character [2 q% on the terminal screen upon closing. The weird characters even appears when I press : inside neovim.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Nvim 0.1.7, that happens because your terminal (1) doesn't support cursor shape control sequences, and (2) doesn't properly ignore unknown sequences. To avoid it, put this in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE=0
```

That's also mentioned in `man nvim`.

---

In Nvim 0.2, cursor styling is controlled by the `guicursor` option. If you see "weird characters" like `[2 q%`, it means your terminal (probably) doesn't support this feature, but `guicursor` was enabled somewhere in your configuration. Disable `guicursor` by setting it empty:

```
:set guicursor=
```

(Nvim disables `guicursor` by default if it's not sure about your terminal. But if you set `guicursor` anyway, Nvim will send the cursor shape control sequences to the terminal.)